# WCF in 2012 R2 server rejecting basic http binding with credentials from client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have stumbled upon a great problem. Server side runs on .net with basicHttpBinding over Basic security on transport level. So here we go:

Server web.config (IIS basic auth = ON, all other = off, protocol = HTTP):

```
<basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

In client we have same basicHttpBinding.

App.exe.config:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Default" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedResponse" maxBufferPoolSize="524288000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536000" maxArrayLength="65536000" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
            </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Also, I happen to know that in windows 8.1 and server 2012 R2 basicHttpBinding method is restricted to transfer credentials. So the question is what are my options? Can I avoid using SSL over https? If no, then how should my config look for https with wsHttpBinding on both sides? Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, you should change the line:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
```

to

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
```

to use transport security with basic http binding. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx) details step by step how to configure the service in IIS

Comment: In such case my clients will need to be under one domain including the server, for AD to work with Windows authentication type. Yet I need a basic authentication scheme. I might be wrong if there were changes to windows authentication as well.

Comment: That's correct.I guess you want to use custom credentials like user name and password. If that is the case, have a look at this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti